# Part of content only shows after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

Part of content doesn´t show on the first time i open this specific html page, the other pages of my website seems to be ok, after refresh the page, the content loads fine.

[Content not showing - Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwFVm.jpg)

[Content not showing - Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m83KD.jpg)

This happends in desktop, and mobile on small resolutions,

On full screen, content seems to show as it should.

I´m using a Javascript script to change page content `src='js/dynamicpage.js'` & `src='js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js'` could this be the problem?

Any help would be helpfull

```css
body {
 background-color: white;
}

a { 
    color: inherit; 
} 

a:hover { 
    color: inherit; 
} 

#logo{
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
}

#logo-footer{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 30px;
}

#footer-info{
    text-align: center;
    width: %;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: darkgrey;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 2px;
    padding: 20px;

}

#camada{
    width: 65%;
    position:relative;
    right: 50px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    z-index:0;
}

#list{
    text-align: center;
    padding-right:9%;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight:lighter;
    z-index:1;
    
}

#nav ul li {
   display:inline;
}


#social-icons{
    width: 15px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 5px;
}

#social-icons:hover
{
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
        transform: scale(1.3);
}


#list .current {
        color: #242424;
        font-weight: bolder;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #bfbfbf;
}

#dog-parents-flags{
    width: 25px;
}

#dog-parents-gender{
    width: 65px;
}

#dog-parents-name{
    
}

#option1{
    margin: 0 0 3px 0;
}

#option2{
    margin: 0 0 3px 0;
}

#option3{
    margin: 0 0 3px 0;
}

#option4{
    margin: 0 0 3px 0;
}

#option5{
    margin: 0 0 3px 0;
}












.cta-100 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 8%;
  padding-top: 7%;
}
.col-md-4{
    padding-bottom:20px;
}

.white {
  color: #fff !important;
}
.mt{float: left;margin-top: -20px;padding-top: 20px;}
.bg-blue-ui {
  background-color: #708198 !important;
}
figure img{width:300px;}

#blogCarousel {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.blog .carousel-indicators {
  left: 0;
  top: -50px;
  height: 50%;
}


/* The colour of the indicators */

.blog .carousel-indicators li {
  background: #708198;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

.blog .carousel-indicators .active {
  background: #0fc9af;
}




.item-carousel-blog-block {
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 15px;
}

.item-box-blog {
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 4;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item-box-blog-image {
  position: relative;
}

.item-box-blog-image figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.item-box-blog-date {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  top: -20px;
  right: 8px;
  background-color: #41cb52;
}

.item-box-blog-date span {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.item-box-blog-date span.mon {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.item-box-blog-date span.day {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.item-box-blog-body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.item-heading-blog a h5 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  text-decoration:none;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

.item-box-blog-heading a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.item-box-blog-data p {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.item-box-blog-data p i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.item-box-blog-text {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mt-10 {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.btn.bg-blue-ui.white.read {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.btn.bg-blue-ui.white.read:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px inset #4d5f77;
}


.container-ourdogs{
}

.dog-gender{
    width: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 13%;
}

disponible{
    font-size: 11px;
    color: green;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

notdisponible{
    font-size: 11px;
    color: red;
    margin-left: -15px;
}


.fa-envelope {
  color: white;
}




h3.h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 1.7em;
}


/********************* DOGS SLIDER CSS **********************/

.product-grid8 {
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}

.product-grid8 .product-image8 {
  border: 1px solid #e4e9ef;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .3s ease 0s
}

.product-grid8:hover .product-image8 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15)
}

.product-grid8 .product-image8 a {
  display: block
}

.product-grid8 .product-image8 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}

.product-grid8 .pic-1 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s ease-out 0s
}

.product-grid8:hover .pic-1 {
  opacity: 0
}

.product-grid8 .pic-2 {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-out 0s
}

.product-grid8:hover .pic-2 {
  opacity: 1
}

.product-grid8 .social {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 13px;
  right: 13px;
  z-index: 1
}

.product-grid8 .social li {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(3px);
  transition: all .5s ease 0s
}

.product-grid8:hover .social li {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0)
}

.product-grid8:hover .social li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: .1s
}

.product-grid8:hover .social li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: .2s
}

.product-grid8:hover .social li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: .4s
}

.product-grid8 .social li a {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: block;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out
}

.product-grid8 .social li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  border-color: #000
}

.product-grid8 .product-discount-label {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 15px 4px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0081c2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(34% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(34% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%)
}

.product-grid8 .product-content {
  padding: 20px 0 0;
}

.product-grid8 .price {
  color: #242424;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.product-grid8 .price span {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  margin-left: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.product-grid8 .product-shipping {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.product-grid8 .title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  transition: all .3s ease 0s;
  position: relative;
}

.product-grid8 .title a {
  color: #000
}

.product-grid8 .title a:hover {
  color: #0081c2
}

.product-grid8 .all-deals {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2e353b;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 22px 5px;
  transition: all .5s ease 0s
}

.product-grid8 .all-deals .icon {
  margin-left: 7px
}

.product-grid8 .all-deals:hover {
  background-color: #0081c2
}

@media only screen and (max-width:990px) {
  .product-grid8 {
    margin-bottom: 30px
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png"/>


    <link href="css/bootstrap-4.0.0.css" rel="stylesheet">      
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>       
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script> 
    
    <!-- Custom Scripts -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js'></script>  
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/dynamicpage.js'></script>
      
  </head>
 
  <body>
     
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 60px">
  
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <div style="height:160px;text-align: center;">
                 <img id="logo" src="images/logo_1.png"></img>
            </div>
            <br>

            <div style="height:100px">
                <nav id="nav" >
                    <ul id="list">
                        <li style="list-style-type: none;" id="option1"><a class="current" href="index.html" >Home</a></li>
                        <li style="list-style-type: none;"  id="option2"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li style="list-style-type: none;"  id="option3"><a href="ourdogs.html">Our Dogs</a></li>
                        <li style="list-style-type: none;"  id="option4"><a href="ourpuppies.html">Puppies</a></li>
                        <li style="list-style-type: none;" id="option5"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav> 
            </div>
         </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        </div>
           <hr>
           
        <!-- PAGEWRAP & GUTS IS A DYNAMIC JS SCRIPT TO CHANGE PAGE CONTENT -->

        <div id="page-wrap" style="height: auto px;">
        <div class="row" id="main-content">
            <div class="col-sm-12" id="guts">
                <h2 style="color: #242424"></h2>
                <br>

        <!-- DOG 1 -->
                          
<div class="container-ourdogs">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="product-grid8">
                <div class="product-image8">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="pic-1" src="images/our_dogs/1.png">
                        <img class="pic-2" src="images/our_dogs/2.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="product-content">
                    <div class="price">Rusty Viking
                        <span><img src="images/male.png" class="dog-gender" ></img></span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="product-shipping">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a dictum purus, at tempus risus. Integer sapien nisl, pellentesque eu iaculis ut, luctus ac ligula. Praesent eu risus nunc.</span>
                
                    <hr>            
                    <!-- DOG MOTHER -->
                    <span><img id="dog-parents-flags" src="images/Flags/pt.PNG"></img><span style=" vertical-align: middle;margin-left: 7px;" >Rusty Viking - <span style="color: #bfbfbf ">Vikingbull´s</span></span></span>
        
                    <br>
        
                    <!-- DOG FATHER -->
                    <span><img id="dog-parents-flags" src="images/Flags/sw.PNG"></img><span style="vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 7px;" >Example Warrior - <span style="color: #bfbfbf ">Examplebull</span></span></span>  
                 
                
                <!-- DOG 2 -->
                
                      <h3 class="title" style="text-align: center;"></h3>
                </div>
                    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="product-grid8">
                <div class="product-image8">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="pic-1" src="images/our_dogs/3.png">
                        <img class="pic-2" src="images/our_dogs/4.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="product-content">
                    <div class="price">Rusty Viking
                        <span><img src="images/female.png" class="dog-gender" ></img></span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="product-shipping">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a dictum purus, at tempus risus. Integer sapien nisl, pellentesque eu iaculis ut, luctus ac ligula. Praesent eu risus nunc.</span>
                
                    <hr>            
                    <!-- DOG MOTHER -->
                    <span><img id="dog-parents-flags" src="images/Flags/pt.PNG"></img><span style=" vertical-align: middle;margin-left: 7px;" >Rusty Viking - <span style="color: #bfbfbf ">Vikingbull´s</span></span></span>
        
                    <br>
        
                    <!-- DOG FATHER -->
                    <span><img id="dog-parents-flags" src="images/Flags/sw.PNG"></img><span style="vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 7px;" >Example Warrior - <span style="color: #bfbfbf ">Examplebull</span></span></span>  
       
                
                <!-- DOG 3 -->
                
                
                    <h3 class="title" style="text-align: center;"></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="product-grid8">
                <div class="product-image8">     
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="pic-1" src="images/our_dogs/5.png">
                        <img class="pic-2" src="images/our_dogs/6.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="product-content">
                    <div class="price">Rusty Viking
                        <span><img src="images/female.png" class="dog-gender" ></img></span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="product-shipping">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a dictum purus, at tempus risus. Integer sapien nisl, pellentesque eu iaculis ut, luctus ac ligula. Praesent eu risus nunc.</span>
                     
                    <hr>            
                    <!-- DOG MOTHER -->
                    <span><img id="dog-parents-flags" src="images/Flags/pt.PNG"></img><span style=" vertical-align: middle;margin-left: 7px;" >Rusty Viking - <span style="color: #bfbfbf ">Vikingbull´s</span></span></span>
        
                    <br>
        
                    <!-- DOG FATHER -->
                    <span><img id="dog-parents-flags" src="images/Flags/sw.PNG"></img><span style="vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 7px;" >Example Warrior - <span style="color: #bfbfbf ">Examplebull</span></span></span>  
 
                
                    <h3 class="title" style="text-align: center;"></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>                                                  
                <br>
                 <hr>
             </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
        </div>
      <br>
      <br>
    
    <!-- FOOTER -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img id="logo-footer" src="images/logo_2.png"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div id="footer-info">
                    <p>Guarda, Portugal</p>
                    <p>example@bullterrier.pt</p>
                    <p>+351 922 222 222</p>
                    <p><a href="https://www.instagram.com"><img id="social-icons" src="images/fb-icon.png"></img></a></p>
                    <p><a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img id="social-icons" src="images/instagram-icon.png"></img></a></p>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="height: 30px"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to launch scripts at the end of body tag or set attribute 'defer' inside script's tag, it'll guarantee that scripts will launch only after all components of the page is loaded.

for instance:

```
<script defer type='text/javascript' src='js/dynamicpage.js'></script>
```

Comment: Hello @Koldun Maksim , The problem still persists, sometimes it loads all the content, sometime cuts it, and when it cuts, it´s on the same part.

Comment: do you have an example on github or elsewhere or is it private ?